# Post Request to Spring Boot Java request returns 403. Get request is returning 200 ok

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm creating a simple todo list application to practice java. and I'm getting the below error.

The error I receive is :

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/list/create 403 (Forbidden)`

I do have simple google login activated in the application.

Here is how to reproduce it.

Here is my ListController:

```
package com.taskboard.app.controller;

import com.taskboard.app.model.Lists;
import com.taskboard.app.service.ListsService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.rmi.ServerException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/list")
public class ListController {

     private final ListsService listsService;

     public ListController(ListsService listsService) {
         this.listsService = listsService;
     }

     @PostMapping(
             path = "/create",
             consumes = "application/json",
             produces = "application/json"
     )
     public ResponseEntity<Lists> createList(@RequestBody Lists list) throws ServerException {
         Lists newlist = listsService.createList(list);
         if (newlist == null) {
             throw new ServerException("List not created");
         } else {
             return new ResponseEntity<>(newlist, HttpStatus.CREATED);
         }
     }

     @GetMapping(path = "/all",
             produces = "application/json")
     public List<Lists> getAllLists() {
         System.out.println("printing name from getall lists");
         return listsService.getAllLists();
     }

     @GetMapping(path = "{id}")
     public Optional<Lists> getList(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
         return listsService.getList(id);
     }
```

Here is the UserController:

```
// create a UserController
package com.taskboard.app.controller;

import com.taskboard.app.model.User;
import com.taskboard.app.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {

    private Map userDetails;

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Object login (OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
        userDetails = oAuth2AuthenticationToken.getPrincipal().getAttributes();
        return new RedirectView("http://localhost:3000");
    }

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public Object currentUser(OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
        userDetails = oAuth2AuthenticationToken.getPrincipal().getAttributes();
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

and here is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/taskboard
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=<client-id-here>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=<client-secret-here>
```

When I make a post request from my react frontend using this code:

```
export async function postList(list) {
    return await axios.post('/api/v1/list/create', list).then((response) => response.data).catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

I get the error when I make a post request from the UI.

Comment: dont you have any spring security configuration? also what kind of Ouath flow are u usisng? r youusisng JWT with atoken or what?

Comment: @GabrielGarcíaGarrido Nope I don't have any spring security configuration yet. I'm using an OAuth2AuthenticationToken. Shared the UserController contents in the question body (just added)

Comment: but in the ajax request I dont see any token

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities that you can try, and I suggest these 2 options.

## 1. CORS Configuration

```
@CrossOrigin // <- only add this
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {
...
}
```

## 2. Create Spring Security Configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/list/create").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
}
```